# How to create a sql to fetch the ' text' information that is a blob in INFORMIX database

Tags: sql, linux

Blobs are not allowed in 'distinct clause and when I remove distinct the error shows Blobs are not allowed in union clause.  My goal is to pull the setting notes from the not_note_text column.

```
select distinct-- select the docketed entries
        schedasc.as_lead_caseid as as_lead_caseid, not_caseid, not_seq, not_note_text 
        case when not_docnum = 0 then 'C'
        else 'S' end note_type, not_docnum
        from u_schedule sched, u_asccase schedasc, u_person schedpr, cal2004:notes, u_dktentry, cal2004:permissions
        where sched.sd_dtset >= '$startdate' and sched.sd_dtset <= '$enddate'
        and sched.sd_caseid = schedasc.as_caseid
        and schedasc.as_type != 'rel'
        and schedasc.as_group is NULL
        --and sched.sd_type not like '%zz%'
        and sched.sd_dtsatis is null
        and sched.sd_date_term is null
        and sched.sd_judge_prid = pr_prid
        and schedpr.pr_ao_code = '$judgeaocode'
        --Start Notes Mix
        and not_caseid = schedasc.as_caseid
        and (not_docnum = de_document_num or not_docnum = 0)
        and de_caseid = not_caseid
        and de_seqno = sd_deseqno
        and per_user = not_person
        and per_aocode = 'AALL'
        $notetype_line
        and not_aocode = '$judgeaocode'
        union
        select distinct-- select the docketed entries
        not_caseid as as_lead_caseid, not_caseid, not_seq, not_note_text,
        case when not_docnum = 0 then 'C'
        else 'S' end note_type, not_docnum
        from u_schedule sched, u_person schedpr, cal2004:notes, u_dktentry, cal2004:permissions, u_case
        where sched.sd_dtset >= '$startdate' and sched.sd_dtset <= '$enddate'
        --and sched.sd_caseid = schedasc.as_lead_caseid
        --and schedasc.as_type != 'rel'
        --and schedasc.as_group is NULL
        --and sched.sd_type not like '%zz%'
        and sched.sd_dtsatis is null
        and sched.sd_date_term is null
        and sched.sd_judge_prid = pr_prid
        and schedpr.pr_ao_code = '$judgeaocode'
        and cs_caseid = not_caseid
        and cs_type = 'cv'
        --Start Notes Mix
        and not_caseid = sched.sd_caseid
        and (not_docnum = de_document_num or not_docnum = 0)
        and de_caseid = not_caseid
        and de_seqno = sd_deseqno
        and per_user = not_person
        and per_aocode = 'AALL'
        $notetype_line
        and not_aocode = '$judgeaocode'
        order by as_lead_caseid, not_caseid, note_type desc, not_seq
        " 2>/dev/null |&

while IFS="|" read -p as_lead_caseid not_caseid not_seq not_note note_type not_docnum


do
```

Comment: Can you format the SQL for easier for us?

Comment: Selecting the code and hitting the "{}" button in the editor will mark the code up as code. You even get some syntax hilighting. But now the problem is that this is a big , well, blob of code. A minimal example is likely to get better responses.